# The method filter JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is a function that returns an array according to the second argument (if the country is Japan, it will return only brands of cars from Japan). Is it possible to improve the function using only the filter method?

```
const arr = [
   {  
     "name":"BMW",
     "price":"55 000",
     "country":"Germany",
     "sertificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mercedes-benz",
    "price":"63 000", 
    "country":"Germany",
    "certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mitsubishi",
    "price":"93 000", 
    "constructor":"Bar John",
    "door":"3",
    "country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
    "name":"TOYOTA", 
    "price":"48 000", 
    "max_people":"7",
    "country":"Japan",
    "certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Volkswagen",
    "price":"36 000", 
    "constructor":"Pier Sun",
    "country":"Germany",
    "certificate":"no"
  },
 ];

 function getCountry(arr, country) {
   let obj = arr.filter(function(arr){
      return arr.country === country ? arr.country : '';
   });
   let itemCountry = [{}];
   let newItem = 0;
   Object.keys(obj).forEach (item => (obj[item]!==null) ? (itemCountry[newItem]=obj[item] , newItem++): '');
   return itemCountry;
}

console.log(getCountry(arr,"Japan"));  // or any other country
```

Comment: How about `function getCountry(arr, country) {
  return arr.filter(function(arr) {
    return arr.country === country;
  });
}`

Comment: You don't need any of code after the filter, it's basically not doing anything here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no need of any code after `filter()`.Here is the version using [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
const arr = [ { "name":"BMW", "price":"55 000", "country":"Germany", "sertificate":"yes" }, { "name":"Mercedes-benz", "price":"63 000", "country":"Germany", "sertificate":"yes" }, { "name":"Mitsubishi", "price":"93 000", "constructor":"Bar John", "door":"3", "country":"Japan", }, { "name":"TOYOTA", "price":"48 000", "max_people":"7", "country":"Japan", "sertificate":"yes" }, { "name":"Volkswagen", "price":"36 000", "constructor":"Pier Sun", "country":"Germany", "sertificate":"no" }, ];

const getCountry = (arr, country) => arr.filter(x => x.country === country);
console.log(getCountry(arr,"Japan"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help.

```
arr.filter(i => i.country === "Japan");
```

You can learn more about filter [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 1):

You could go a step ahead and use an abstract solution, where you can add a key and a wanted value for filtering the array.

```js
const
    getItems = (array, key, value) => array.filter(o => o[key] === value),
    data = [{ name: "BMW", price: "55 000", country: "Germany", sertificate: "yes" }, { name: "Mercedes-benz", price: "63 000", country: "Germany", certificate: "yes" }, { name: "Mitsubishi", price: "93 000", constructor: "Bar John", door: "3", country: "Japan" }, { name: "TOYOTA", price: "48 000", max_people: "7", country: "Japan", certificate: "yes" }, { name: "Volkswagen", price: "36 000", constructor: "Pier Sun", country: "Germany", certificate: "no" }];

console.log(getItems(data, "country", "Japan"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can only use `Array.filter` for this.

Using the destructuring assignment `{country}` in the arrow function, just pluck the `country` property from the array of objects and use it for comparison with the supplied country filter criteria:

```js
const arr = [ { "name":"BMW", "price":"55 000", "country":"Germany", "sertificate":"yes" }, { "name":"Mercedes-benz", "price":"63 000", "country":"Germany", "sertificate":"yes" }, { "name":"Mitsubishi", "price":"93 000", "constructor":"Bar John", "door":"3", "country":"Japan", }, { "name":"TOYOTA", "price":"48 000", "max_people":"7", "country":"Japan", "sertificate":"yes" }, { "name":"Volkswagen", "price":"36 000", "constructor":"Pier Sun", "country":"Germany", "sertificate":"no" }, ];
function getCountry(arr, filterCountry) {
   return arr.filter(({country}) => {
      return country === filterCountry;
   });
}

console.log(getCountry(arr,"Japan"));  // or any other country
```